# Bash Script Evaluate String Problems

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to create a script to automatically delete all of the tables from a database using shell.

The commented out variable $drop works fine, however when I try to substitute in the table

```
for table in $tables
do
    command="'drop table ${table}'"

    # drop=$(${login} -e 'drop table test') -- this works fine
    drop=$(${login} -e $command)
    echo $drop
    # echo -e "Removed table ${table}"
done
```

Comment: turn on shell debugging to see what values are being used for $command, etc. add `set -vx` before your loop. to turn off, you can use `set +vx`. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, I used this and got these results:`+ for table in '$tables'
+ set -vx
+ command=''\''drop table property_thumbnail'\'''
+ for table in '$tables'` @shellter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(major edit)*

The issue is with your use of quotes. In your code, since you do not quote `$command` it is subject to word splitting by the shell. The $login command receives these arguments: `"-e", "'drop", "table", "table_name'"` -- note the stray single quotes in the second and last elements.

Do this:

```
command="drop table $table"
drop=$($login -e "$command")
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and am still having problems. I don't think drop should be an array, rather, it takes $table from the $tables array. When I use the syntax shown above, the command does not show at all?

Comment: Current Code: ` command="drop table ${table}"
  drop=("$login" -e "${command}")
  echo "${drop[@]}"` which prints out the correct commands, but doesn't actually run the command. When I try $("${drop[@]}") it shows error "no such directory"@glenn jackman

Comment: @JonMorehouse, I misunderstood your question -- it is not clear what `$login` is. I have rewritten my answer.